# Did the Battle of Gog Umagog happen already?

Tags: ezekiel--the-book, sanhedrin, gog, umagog

I’ve been reading a lot of Ezekiel Chapter 38 and on with Talmud Sanhedrin 97a and on and it seems from there that the order of events before the coming of mashiach need to happen in order for mashiach ben david to come.

So my question is: have these event already taken place in said order and if they have why do us Jewish people continue to be persecuted during modern times.

Additionally, if the last battle against Israel will be with gog unagog and cohorts attacking israel isn’t it supposed to be in the land of Israel against all of israel.

And hashem on that day will destroy all of Israel’s enemies and their corpses will be left for food of the beasts of the field and birds in the sky to feed on a great feast for them.

If this has happened already, When in history has this happened?

Comment: Why would you think this may have happened already?

Answer (score 0):

This will be an unorthodox answer:

Prophetic visions are not absolute. If you read the Book of Daniel, the apocalypse was supposed to happen during the time of the Maccabees, but that clearly did not happen. Prophetic visions are a nudge towards our own actions and objectives. Prophetic visions are not so much a full proof vision of the future, but a "nudge" for us to do something.

Look at 1 Kings 22:1-23 to see what I mean.

Expect the unexpected.

Comment: There is a principle that a prophecy of a bad decree can be overturned: 

Yesodei haTorah 10:4